# How to relate two SQL tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables `cars` and `owners`. `OWNERNO` is the primary key in table `owners`. I would like to know how I can put ownerno as foreign key in the `cars` table and still insert values that are different from my first table

**cars**

```
REGNO   MAKE     COLOUR PRICE  OWNERNO
---------------------------------------
KAA462J FORD     RED    120000 824 
KAB230Q SKODA    BLUE   110000 828 
KAV201W MERCEDES BLUE   220000 832 
KAA306T TOYOTA   BLUE   130000 836
```

**Owners**

```
OWNERNO OWNERNAME OWNERADDRESS 
---------------------------------------
724     Atieno    Otieno 567 Umoja 
828     Hassan    Hussein 987 Kayole 
932     Wanjiru   Wanjiri 735 Kariobangi
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Would you please try to describe what you want to add?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "still insert values that are different from my first table"?

Comment: I didn't get the second part of the question. What are we trying to achieve here? As it seems to me that `Field OWERNO` is already an `FK` of `TABLE cars`

Comment: Are you saying you want to put `ownerno`'s into the `cars` table which don't exist in the `owners` table? If so, why?

Comment: Yes, Schwern OP's query is to insert records in cars table for which ownerid is not present in owners table

Comment: Sometime people new to SQL expect there is a way to define a relation ship between related tables so that updates to both the tables happen "auto-magically" is this what you are hoping?

Comment: Here ownerno is the primary key in owners table and foreign key in cars table Insert  into owners(ownerno, ownername, owneraddress) values(724, 'Atieno', '567 Umoja');                                                                                                                  Insert  into cars(regno, make, colour, ownerno) values('KAA462J',  'Ford', 'Red', 120000, 824);

Comment: Yes Schwern because I have this type of question                                                   List all the cars Regno, Color, Price and their owners’ names and addresses including the car that the owner name is not known.  How can I answer it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, you *can't* define a column as a foreign key and then place values in it that are not in the referenced table/column. That is the very purpose of a foreign key - to assure referential integrity.

However, you *can* have a column in your cars table that points to the `ownerno` in the owner table without it being defined as a foreign key. You can still `JOIN` the tables using that id:

```
    SELECT REGNO, MAKE, COLOUR, PRICE, OWNERNAME, OWNERADDRESS
        FROM Cars 
        LEFT JOIN Owners ON Cars.OWNERNO = Owners.OWNERNO
        ORDER BY REGNO
```

It's important in this case to use `LEFT JOIN` so that you will get all the records from the Cars table even if there is no corresponding Owner record that matches the `OWNERNO` in the Cars table.

Comment: Thanks so much . I have understood now.Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to left join as cars left join owner on owners_id would mean all the owners_id which are present in cars both matched and unmatched from cars table to owners table output those.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems unclear and somewhat not possible can say.

A foreign key is made to relate records from one table to the other. How can a record be inserted when its not there to relate in the other table.

Workaround use candidate key (Multiple keys) but you should agree the query seems off topic

Comment: Okay.Now I get it . Thank you